# Setting up proxy according to url in Scrapy

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, tor, socks

I have a list of URL some of them contain .onion sites and other a clear net sites I'm wondering is there a way to set up Scrapy so that according to the URL, so it either uses a dedicated clear net proxy for normal .com and .net sites or it uses a Socks5 proxy for .onion sites

```
def random_dedicate_proxy():
    dedicated_ips = [  proxy1, proxy2, proxy3
                ]
    dedicated_proxies = [{'http':'http://' + ip, 'https':'https://' + ip} for ip in dedicated_ips]
    return choice(dedicated_proxies)

def proxy_selector(url):
    TOR_CLIENT = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
    if '.onion' in url:
        proxy  = {'http': TOR_CLIENT, 'https': TOR_CLIENT}
    else:
        proxy = random_dedicate_proxy()
    return proxy

def get_urls_from_spreadsheet():
    fname = 'list_of_stuff.csv'
    url_df = pd.read_csv(fname,usecols=['URL'],keep_default_na=False)
    URL = url_df.URL.dropna()
    urls = [clean_url(url) for url in URL if url != '']
    return urls

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "basic"
    rotate_user_agent = True
    start_urls = get_urls_from_spreadsheet()


    def parse(self, response):
        item = StatusCehckerItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['status_code'] = response.status
        item['time'] = time.time()
        response.meta['proxy'] = proxy_selector(response.url)
        return item
```

when using this code I get a `DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: mqqrfjmfu2i73bjq.onion/.`

Comment: What did you put as ``proxy`` here ``{'proxy': proxy}``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `HTTPPROXY_ENABLED` is set to `True` in spider settings. And then in your `start_requests` method pick the method to proxy URLs.

```
class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    custom_settings = {
        'HTTPPROXY_ENABLED': True # can also set this in the settings.py file
    }
    name = "basic"
    rotate_user_agent = True

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = get_urls_from_spreadsheet()
        for url in urls:
            proxy = proxy_selector(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={'proxy': proxy})

    def parse(self, response):
        item = StatusCehckerItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['status_code'] = response.status
        item['time'] = time.time()
        return item
```

Comment: thank you for the answer when I run your suggestion i get the error `url = url.strip() AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip` I think thats because my proxies are a dictionary for http and https is there a way for me to change that so scrapy can accept them? do I specify `meta={'http_proxy':proxy, https_proxy:proxy}`

Comment: AFAIK your `meta` needs to have a dictionary with key `proxy` and 1 URL. So it should look like `meta={'proxy': proxy}`.